# Full screen background that emanates from an element near the centre of screen

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed, full screen background. I have another image a few hundred pixels from the top that I want the background to appear to emanate from. Looks good here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7oyl.jpg but when the browser is resized the centre of the background image moves vertically but the foreground image remains fixed so they are no longer aligned. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Some more info. The foreground image is position:relative, and here is the CSS for the background image:

`.background {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image: url('/background.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
}`

Comment: Just to clarify, the foreground image is fixed in one position, and the background resizes with the page?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell what's going on without some code, but...

```
background{
  background-image: url("my-image.jpg");
  background-position: center top;
  background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

This will ensure that the distance from the top of the window to the other image never changes because the height of the image remains the same, and the position of the image is always flushed to the top. The problem that you'll encounter is that depending on the width of the device your background may stretch.